# UIImageView doesn't remove old image when going back with the navigation control

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview, back-button

I have a UIImageViews within a UIScrollView. Tapping an image moves to another view controller where I can edit info that will then change the original tapped UIImage. 
When I go back via the nav controller the new image does appear (dependent on the changes made in the 2nd view controller) however the old image also appears behind it.

If I go back another level then forward again the old image is now gone. How can I fix this without have to go back and forth?

(the code is long and complex so don't know if it will help to post it)

---

Found it used

```
-(void) viewDidDisappear: (BOOL) animated {
  [super viewDidDisappear:animated]; 
  for (UIImageView *img in [MyScrollView subview]) {
    [img removeFromSuperview]; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `imageView.image = nil;` before setting the image.

Comment: can you post some code specially when you are navigating to other viewcontroller and coming back and how are you initializing your imageview

Answer (score 0):

try this in viewDidDisappear

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
}
```

Comment: can't sorry. would if I could, not enough reputation yet. I'm just new.

Answer (score 0):

then before you set new image empty or nill the image view like this

```
imgview.image=nil;
```

then set new image i hope this is work if any problem then comment :-)

Comment: I tried this and the old imageview was still visible. I had to remove the UIImageViews from their superview during ViewDisDisappear.